Show that the function $f(n) = \sigma(n)\varphi(n)$ is a multiplicative function and calculate $f(p^k)$.
Let $f(n) = \sigma(n)\varphi(n)$ where $\sigma(n)=\sigma_1(n)= \sum_{d|n}d$ and $\varphi(n)$ is Euler function. Show that $f(n)$ is a multiplicative function and calculate $f(p^k)$, where $p$ is a prime number and $k \in \mathbb N$. Then next show, that $\frac{6n^2}{\pi^2} < f(n)\text{ for } n \geq 2$.

More generally, the pointwise product of any two multiplicative functions is also multiplicative.

In the version of Latex supported on this site, dollar signs must be used to indicate text which should be rendered.  If you click on "Edit" you can see the syntax I used to format your post (basically the same as yours with the dollar signs and some extra spacing and line breaks added).

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions

As mentioned in the comments, the multiplicativity follows quickly from the multiplicativity of $\sigma(x)$ and $\varphi(x)$.
As for $f(p^k)$, it suffices to know $\sigma(p^k)$ and $\varphi(p^k)$, both of which are pretty easy and standard results.
For $\sigma(p^k)$, note that the only divisors of $p^k$ are all the powers of $p$ with exponent at most $k$, so $\sigma(p^k)=1+p+p^2+\cdots+p^k$. This is a geometric series and by the well-known formula for geometric series, $\sigma(p^k)=\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{p-1}$.
For $\varphi(p^k)$, the only numbers not coprime to $p^k$ are the multiples of $p$. There are exactly $p^{k-1}$ of these in the range $1$ to $p^k$, so $\varphi(p^k)=p^{k}-p^{k-1}=p^{k-1}(p-1)$.
So finally $f(p^k)=\sigma(p^k)\varphi(p^k)=p^{k-1}(p^{k+1}-1)$.
As for the last part, it helps to write $f(p^k)=p^{2k}(1-\frac{1}{p^{k+1}})$.
Now we can write any natural number $n$ as a product of primes $n=p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_j^{k_j}$. Using the multiplicativity,
$f(n)=f(p_1^{k_1})\cdots f(p_j^{k_j})$
$=p_1^{2k_1}(1-\frac{1}{p_1^{k_1+1}})\cdots p_j^{2k_j}(1-\frac{1}{p_j^{k_j+1}})$
$=(p_1^{k_1}\cdots p_j^{k_j})^2(1-\frac{1}{p_1^{k_1+1}})\cdots(1-\frac{1}{p_j^{k_j+1}})$
$=n^2\prod_{i=1}^j (1-\frac{1}{p_i^{k_i+1}}).$
As each $k_i$ is at least 1 (or they just wouldn't be included), $(1-\frac{1}{p_i^{k_i+1}}) \geq (1-\frac{1}{p_i^2})$.
So $f(n) \geq n^2 \prod_{i=1}^j (1-\frac{1}{p_i^2})$.
This finite product is larger than the product over all primes (as each term is less than 1), so
$f(n) > n^2\prod_{\text{p prime}} (1-\frac{1}{p^2}) = n^2 \frac{6}{\pi^2}$ using the Euler product for $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.

Can you still help me and solve that $f(n) < n^2$

@Josef213 You should be able to show that easily with what is above.

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
